# Generate 1description+1picture refering to it, via a link, in this php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database

It's a portfolio with 4 section. Each page has 1 category, that category has 4 projects represented by 4 links.
This is my list of links/projects (extracted from database), and appearing via a loop :

```
<?php 
$x = 0;
while ($x < 16){        
if (($categories[$x] == $section) && (isset($categories[$x])))
{
echo '<li><a href="#'.$ids[$x].'" class="close";">'.$titres[$x].'</a></li>';
}
}
$x++;
?>
```

Each links makes appear a description, which also comes from my database via this loop :

```
<?php 
$x = 0;
while ($x < 16)
{       
if (($categories[$x] == $section) && (isset($categories[$x])))
{   
echo '<p id="'.$x.'" class="description"> '.$description[$x].'</p>';
}
$x++;
} 
?>
```

HERE IS MY PROBLEM :
By clicking on the link's project appears :
- the right description appears, 
- and the picture of the project too. .
I tried to find a jquery way .. but give up .. i tried with javascript .. doesn't work.
I about to break my laptop.

DETAILS :
My database only has 1 table with everything included.

```
$sql = "SELECT categorie FROM Projets WHERE categorie=".$categorie;
$tabCat = getCategorie($categorie);
$categories = array();
$titres = array();
$description = array();
$images = array();
$ids = array();
$i = 0;
while ($donnees = $tabCat->fetch())
{
$categories[$i] = $donnees['categorie'];
$titres[$i]  =$donnees['Titre'];
$description[$i]  = $donnees['Description'];
$images[$i]  = $donnees['Image'];
$ids[$i] = $donnees['id'];
$i++;
}
$tabCat->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to accomplish here but I see some errors in your code anyways, in your first code `class="close";">` you seem to have a double quote too much and also what is the `;` doing in there? In that same file, you've put your `$x++;` outside of your loop, so it will never be incremented inside the loop...

I still find your question confusing in what you are trying to accomplish here, can you be more specific to your problem? Tu peux toujours poser ta question en français aussi, si ça peut t'aider...

Comment: Cool en français c'est mieux, Merci déjè pour ta réponse.

Comment: Je presente un portfolio, composé de 4 categories. Chaque categorie possède une page listant 4 projets, représentés sous forme de 4 liens. ces liens-projets ont été générés par ma base de données.    Mon probleme est que je souhaiterai qu'en fonction du lien cliqué, etla description adéquate apparaisse également ainsi qu'une image.

Comment: Ah je crois que je commence a visualiser. Alors ce que tu voudrais faire c'est d'afficher la desc et l'image lorsque tu cliques sur un lien, pour ce faire tu dois t'arranger pour mettre ces 2 choses dans un <span> ou <div> que tu vas cacher ou afficher. Donc ensuite utilises la propriété CSS `display:none;` pour cacher et puis `display:inline;` pour afficher, au départ tout tes <span> doivent être cachés donc ajoute cette propriété dans ton while `<span style="display:none"><img...>Desc...</span>` et utilise javascript ou jQuery pour changé la propriété `display` à `display:inline`

Comment: Pour plus d'explications, tu devrais englober tes <p> qui contiennent ton image et description dans des <span> au travers ta boucle, donc par-dessus ton <p>. Fait quelque chose comme ceci: `<span style="display:none"><p id="proj_1">...</p></span>` par défaut elle seront donc toutes cachées. Ensuite sur ton lien, ajoute le javascript event `onclick` et si tu restes en pure javascript alors ca ressemblera a ceci: `<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('proj_1').style.display='inline';`